# Webhook integration between Podio and Zoho people

Tags: podio, zoho

I'm trying to automate my workflow between Podio and Zoho People. For example, when an Employee is added in my HR app, I want to call the Zoho People API to add it there too.

However, I get stuck in the validation phase. I don't get what's the validation process needs to be? What the endpoint I must call? I don't have control over what the Zoho API returns, obviously.

I never worked with webhooks before so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where are you getting error. Podio authentication? Please share the error and sample code